# How to mock ArrayList class using using whenNew method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to mock arraylist to verify the add method but I'm getting the message:

```
FAILED: testInit
Wanted but not invoked:
arrayList.add(<any>);
-> at AsyncRestTemplateAutoConfigurationTest.testInit(AsyncRestTemplateAutoConfigurationTest.java:95)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

The test class I've used is:

```
@Test
    public void testInit() throws Exception {

        ArrayList<AsyncClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = Mockito.mock(ArrayList.class);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(ArrayList.class).withAnyArguments()
                .thenReturn(interceptors);

        Mockito.stub(interceptors.add(Mockito.any())).toReturn(true);
        asyncRestTemplateAutoConfiguration.init();

        Mockito.verify(interceptors).add(Mockito.any());
    }
```

The actual tested code is:

```
List<AsyncClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>(interceptors);
    interceptors.add(new TracingAsyncRestTemplateInterceptor(tracer));
```

I've declared the test class with

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(AsyncRestTemplateAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Where `AsyncRestTemplateAutoConfiguration`is the class, which I'm using to test. Could anyone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle do you want to turn this upvote-worthy comment into an answer?

Comment: @DavidRawson done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your unit test should verify *public observable behavior* which is *return values* and *communication with dependencies* (which does not nessessarily imply to test only `public` methods).

That your production code uses an `ArrayList` to store your data is an *implementation detail* which you don't want to test since it may be changed without changing the units general behavior, in which case your unittest should not fail.

Answer (score 3):

Don't start learning how to unit test using PowerMockito - it will give you bad habits.

Instead, consider working carefully through the [documentation for Mockito](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.15.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html) and you will see how to structure your classes for better testing.

Ideally, your classes should be such that you do not need PowerMockito to test them and you can just rely on plain old Mockito.

If you can arrive at the point where you can write elegant and simple tests using just Mockito, it will be a sign you have grasped the fundamental concepts of unit testing.

You can start by learning how to inject dependencies through the constructor of the class that can be swapped with mocked test doubles on which behaviour can be verified.

Another point to note is, as per the other answer, the internal `ArrayList` in your system under test is an implementation detail. Unless consumers of your system under test can access the `ArrayList` through, say, methods that expose it there is not much point in writing a test against it.

If the state of the internal `ArrayList` affects something from the point of view of the consumer, then try writing a test against that rather than against the internal property.

Good luck with your journey on unit testing!